# GWT lifecycle - Deferred binding at runtime.What happens

Tags: gwt

Can someone explain what happens after the java code is converted to Javascript by the GWT compiler?
how will the compiled javascript reach the client browser and when does this happen.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that javascript produced by GWT will ever reach client browser. 
Because GWT compiler (with default linker), simply creates a bunch of javascript files of disk. It doesn't deliver anything to the client. Compiler just compiles and give you some result it is up to user what to do with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Well from your server, you serve a html page which should contain a  tag that points to your compiled javascript.

Example of what the script tag would look like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://example.com/js/project/project.nocache.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The GWT compiler generates output files as described [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames).

At a very high level. There is a very tiny loader file (the .nocache.) which you should include in a script tag in your page. This file's only job is to determine the correct compiled application code files to request from the server. This load happens asynchronously after the nocache script has loaded.